# Swift JSONDecoder decode Int64 on iOS 10

Tags: ios, json, swift, int64, decodable

There is a bug in iOS 10, that Swift 4's `JSONDecoder` does not decode some huge 64 bit integers from JSON with error *"Parsed JSON number <1522853867156381000> does not fit in Int64."*

This is not happening in iOS 11 and it is a [known bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7119)

None of `NSNumber`, `NSDecimalNumber` and `NSValue` implement the `Decodable` protocol so I have not found a way to decode them from a `Decoder`.

So the question is how to decode such numbers with `Codable`/`Decodable`?

Changing the JSON, to have the numbers as strings, is not an option.

**EDIT:** As there is no workaround we have chosen the "not an option" and updated the server to return 64 bit integers also as strings.

Comment: Did you try to write an extension for `NSNumber` or  `NSDecimalNumber` to implement `Decodable` yourself?

Comment: @mag_zbc extension cannot add a required init method which `Decodable` protocol adds.

Comment: Does it work with NSJSONSerialization? That would be a workaround.

Comment: @MartinR `NSJSONSerialization` works with checking for `NSDecimalNumber`. Problem is that my struct with that Int64 is used in several other structs, i.e. nested, and I would have to switch to `NSJSONSerialization` for every such case and it is a big rewrite... I have also some other structs with smaller Int64s but those could lead to the same issue in the future, so I will have to throw away the whole `Codable` :(